# Animating an ItemsControl in WPF: sliding and fading

Tags: wpf, animation, itemscontrol

I would like to animate when items are added/removed from an ItemsControl. Does anyone have ideas/links on how to achieve this?

I think fading-in should be doable by attaching an animation to the Loaded event. Fading out seems it would be much harder, though.

As for sliding, when an item disappears, I want the rest of the items to slide to collapse the space. This also seems tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to animate item's container. At first, you need to make it transparent, but not hide it. Then you need to animate it's height from original height to zero. And after that you can remove item from item source.

Unfortunately, I can't help you with events and code.